# How To Use 301 Redirect In htaccess To Stop 404 Errors?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've two domains with same name but different TLD like .com and .net.
i'm using blog on ".com" domain and forum on ".net" domains like

Sites 1: "http://www.mywebsite.com/" (blog)
Site 2: "http://www.mywebsite.net/forum" (forum)

I'm facing problem with Google webmaster tool, webmaster tool trying to crawle my .com domain as forum hosted like "www.mydomain.com/forum" however forum not exist on .com domain. its exist on .net domain. so its generate 404 errors.

Please, let me know some code to to redirect ".com/forum/ {Plus Queries} /" to exact ".net/forum/{ Destination }" i believe its help to mark remove 404 errors or help to prevent more errors.

however, today I've set my robots.txt to disable Google crawling on ".com/forum"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root for the *.com* domain, add:

```
Redirect 301 /forum http://www.mywebsite.net/forum
```

If both domains share the same document root, thus sharing the same htaccess file, then you'll need to do an additional check for the host by using mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?forum/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.net/forum/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Jon Lin, Thanks For help, its working for me... One more thing,
I've tags pagination url look like this "http://mydomain.com/tags/apple/page/01/"
Google crawler detected some invalid increment pagination url "http://mydomain.com/tags/apple/page/2/"
and 2 is not exit only 1 page exist...
My question is that, if 2 page not exit its generate 404 error?
How to redirect this not found 404 page to valid url "http://mydomain.com/tags/apple/page/01/"

Comment: @user1218948 it will generate a 404, the best way to deal with it may be to add php code that tries to guess where the browser wanted to go and do a redirect from there. Otherwise, you'll have to use mod_rewrite, and create a redirect for each one of the invalid pagination URLs.